# How to distribute a secret about someone in a group without revealing that person's identity to themselves

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-designs

Let's say I have a group of $n$ people ${p_n}$ and I want to distribute a secret about one specific member of the group, say $p' \in {p_n}$, without them knowing that they are that $p'$. I also want everyone to know that a secret will be told about one person in the group. Is there any way do this? Naively I would say just tell all of *other* people the message, but then in any subsequent use of the method, you would know if you're the person the secret is about because you don't get the message. How can you distribute a message to all n people that contains the secret about one of them without revealing whether or not you're the person the secret is about?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what exactly you mean by "secret"? Is it something that person $p'$ already knows? Something like "One member of the group has a cat face tattoo on her/his thigh"? Because in that case person $p'$ will immediately know it is her/him.

Comment: By "secret" I mean some piece of information that everyone besides p' must know. Everyone must know that this piece of information exists, but only the people who aren't p' should know what it is. I want to figure out how to send out the fact that there IS a secret to everyone, but only reveal the CONTENT of the secret to people besides p'. And the method must be repeatable (i.e. the following year, the person must not be able to reveal the secret from knowing how the dissemination works)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the secret to everyone in the group except for $p'$ and then send a lie about another member to $p'$. I assume that there is no communication between the n people after receiving the message.